# BadPaddingException with Jasypt library

Tags: java, encryption, junit3, jasypt, badpaddingexception

I am not sure whether this is a bug or I am doing some mistake. In either case, I need help from somebody.

We have incorporated Jasypt along with Spring 2.05 in our web application in which we are encrypting some passwords in the properties file. The thing is working smoothly on the Web application. We can even decrypt the passwords from a main method by using BasicTextEncrypor.decrypt(method).

However, we are experiencing problem when we execute of JUnit test cases. As soon as we run the test suite, we get the following stack trace.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.getTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit3TestLoader.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:131)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:114)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:75)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestSuite(TestSuite.java:101)
at com.abc.test.dao.AllTests.suite(AllTests.java:104)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:981)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:725)
at org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor.decrypt(BasicTextEncryptor.java:112)
at org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.java:78)
at org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.convertPropertyValue(EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:115)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperties(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:95)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:72)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:91)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:75)
at com.abc.test.ApplicationContextUtils.getTestApplicationContext(ApplicationContextUtils.java:18)
at com.abc.test.BaseTestCase.<clinit>(BaseTestCase.java:45)
```

I dived into the source code of Jasypt and came to know that behind the scene javax.crypto.BadPaddingException is thrown. I am not sure why there is difference between making the same call directly from the main method and executing the same thing via JUnit framework everything else (e.g., password) is same.

Comment: did you find an answer for it ?

Comment: In my case this happen from encryption took place on Ubuntu VM and now I'm trying to decrypt passwords on Mac OS X. Same exception with no changes in between.

Answer (score 0):

This exception can also happen when the String is encrypted with a different JVM version than it is decrypted with. Using same JVM version on both sides (encryption/decryption; server/client) has helped in our case.